# Paragraph Text size is too small in Jquery Mobile + Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've read the other posts re text CSS in JQuery Mobile and resolutions, but can't seem to find an answer my case:

the paragraph text is too small (i.e., any text inside standard

tags) on high(ish) resolution devices like a Galaxy SII . All other elements are satisfactory.

Seems like this should be a simple fix but I have been banging my head.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

how about a simple  tag?

```
html, body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```